# jQuery appendTo doesn't append

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML:

```
<table id="ParamTbl">
<tbody>
    <tr id="ParamRow">
        <td><label for="paramname[]">Name: </label><input type="text" name="paramname[]" class="paramname"></td>
        <td><label for="paramval[]">Value: </label><input type="text" name="paramval[]"></td>
        <td><label for="paramtype[]">Type: </label><select name="paramtype[]">
                <option selected="true">String</option>
                <option>Double</option>
                <option>Object</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><div id="clrList">X</div></td>
        <td><div id="addrow">Add Param</div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
function addParam(ParamName){
    $('#ParamTbl').css('background-color','yellow');
    var clone = $('#ParamTbl').closest("tr").clone();
    clone.appendTo('#ParamTbl').find(":input").val(ParamName);
    $('#ParamTbl').closest("td").remove();
}
```

`css('background-color','yellow');` is for debugging purposes, I had a few `alerts()` in there too, the function is called ok, and the ParamName is handed to it ok.
So, the question: why isn't my row appended?

Comment: I don't see you calling `addParam`. can you make a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete redesign

HTML

```
<table id="ParamTbl">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="paramname[]">Name: </label><input type="text" name="paramname[]" class="paramname"/></td>
            <td><label for="paramval[]">Value: </label><input type="text" name="paramval[]"/></td>
            <td><label for="paramtype[]">Type: </label><select name="paramtype[]">
                <option selected="true">String</option>
                <option>Double</option>
                <option>Object</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><div class="clrList">X</div></td>
            <td><div class="addrow">Add Param</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    var $table = $('#ParamTbl');

    $('#ParamTbl').on('click', '.addrow', function(){
        $table.css('background-color','yellow');

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        var clone = tr.clone();
        clone.appendTo($table).find('input[name="paramval[]"]').val('');
        $(this).remove();
    })

    $('#ParamTbl').on('click', '.clrList', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove()
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zTFqv/6/)

Comment: @Borniet which cell do you want to remove

Comment: In my previous code, $('#ParamTbl').closest("td").remove(); removed the last <td></td> from the cloned row.

Comment: @Borniet you want to remove the `Add Row` button

Comment: Indeed, so that it's only placed on the last row.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
var clone = $('#ParamTbl').closest("tr").clone();
```

to:

```
var clone = $('#ParamTbl').find("tr#ParamRow").clone();
```

since [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

`Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.`

Try `find` instead:

`var clone = $('#ParamTbl').find("tr:first").clone();`